# workflow fronted by msmq with net.tcp receive activity

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I have a workflow that is initiated by a msmq message, it does some processing and then calls initialize correlation and waits with a receive activity. So the workflow already has a msmq endpoint, is it possible to add a net.tcp endpoint that would allow a client to correlate with the receive activity?

Answer (score 0):

No, you're not going to be able to do that because the service as a whole is exposed via a specific protocol, not just one operation, just like any other standard SOAP service.

However, what you can do is have the MSMQ based workflow startup another workflow service that has a `Receive`, initializes correlation properly, and then goes back to sleep with another `Receive` waiting for the other consumer.

Further, I believe that's a better approach anyway because the MSMQ service is simply used as an orchestrator then to get things started.